How to model padded surface for a chair?
I'm looking for a simple and efficient way to model a padded surface like this one:


Here's what I was heading for but it's harder than I thought.  Any hints ?


This is technically a duplicate, but there are newer solutions involving cloth simulations with sewing and internal pressure. Such was actually showed off as a showcase of those features when they were added to Blender a while back.
